# How to make nullable properties optional in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type like this:

```js
type City = {
  name: string;
  id: number | null;
};
```

And want to turn it into a type like this:

```js
type City = {
  name: string;
  id?: number;
};
```

I have seen plenty of posts explaining how to make optional types nullable, but I want the opposite here.

Is there any way to create a TypeScript generic function like `OptionalNullable<T>` that handles this?

Comment: To clarify, you want all nullable types to be optional generically or..?

Comment: yes! turn all nullable types into optional types on an object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
type PickNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? P : never]: T[P]
}

type PickNotNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? never : P]: T[P]
}

type OptionalNullable<T> = {
  [K in keyof PickNullable<T>]?: Exclude<T[K], null>
} & {
  [K in keyof PickNotNullable<T>]: T[K]
}
```

I created two utility types which pick all nullable not non-nullable properties from a type respectively. We can use these to construct a new type where all nullable properties are made optional. I also used `Exclude` so to get rid of `null`.

It can be used like this:

```
type City = {
  name: string;
  id: number | null;
};

type Test = OptionalNullable<City>
// {
//    id?: number | undefined;
// } & {
//     name: string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwglqKBeKBvAUFKA7AhgWwgC4oBnYAJzmwHMBuTKOAExOwFd8AjCCqAHxzsANsIYBfBulCQoABTgBjANYA5EcNxdhEADwAVAHzI0jANpym2KMoggA9gDMo+qLlJDRUCAA9gEbGYPfQsAXSgAfnkoNggAN15QkhC5UPRxdGlwaAUVVXtgdVEtHQNjFAwsCysbOycXNw8OL19-QOCwyJx43hj5JJcw9MyZaAB5MGA4ezxhIs1tPSMTSqgzAGka2wdnXLUNEqXDUIiSAFEfRWF2ZiWN0IAaT2FDdKgAMlMqzepanfklGoCvNDmUBiF1mkMllZPoIOQTBMpjNcHMDotdPBQIYgA)

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

Building on @tobias-s's excellent answer, `OptionalNullable<T>` can be made recursive.

```
type OptionalNullable<T> = T extends object ? {
  [K in keyof PickNullable<T>]?: OptionalNullable<Exclude<T[K], null>>
} & {
  [K in keyof PickNotNullable<T>]: OptionalNullable<T[K]>
} : T;
```

It can be used like this:

```
type State = {
  name: string;
  id: number | null;
  capitol: City;
  cities: City[];
};

type City = {
  name: string;
  id: number | null;
};

type StateWithoutIds = OptionalNullable<State>;

let test: StateWithoutIds = {
  name: "Indiana",
  capitol: { name: "Indianapolis" },
  cities: [
    { name: "Indianapolis" },
    { name: "Fort Wayne" }
  ]
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQUoDt4FsIAuKAZ2ACcBLHAcwG4soqATEnAV3wCMIKoAPrg4AbEY2wBjeGCrAA9iJIBhOSAlRJcqhFIq1AbQC6jAL6MMoSFFWgoqTNjyES5anQ2t2XXvyGcxMwsraAAFKkkAawA5URF4bhEIAB4AFQA%20e3QmA1DmHChIiBB5ADMoVKh4UmExKAgADyQcFhrU3KMoAH4oPPYIADc%20IxJ20KMMcwxLcDCImPlgWLEEpLTMhxy8mkLisoqqmoCReqaIFraO7txBvigScdGOyeDZqAB5MGAqeTwRZfiiRSGSylUazVaUHk3AAVhBJMBro4oAYANL5XYlcrhKIA1bA9JGLokT7fX7wf5xfHJACiDUkIg4LGBaKMABpaiJ0ulJlAAGTZbBojFFLG9ebRRZ4oHrEYfL4-P7StbtVFGHmme4VV7WOCICAAdTkAAt5BxgABJSGoUmKinKlJ6pDpCxJRFIcgkJ2Gk1my3WwW4AjEKAAIgtLSo8DwobZTGksgUSnQQZcYYjLCjeDAiiopFDUFMcak2l0JAMTGwaFTIfDkejMlz%20cLxewKectYAYvIKIiDfAQDgIAXTEwJlMgA)

Comment: Going the other direction (optional to null): [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOGA6w)

Answer (score 0):

You could always write something like this assuming that you only want to change a set amount of keys in the object

```js
type City = {
  name: string;
  id: number | null;
};

type CityCorrect = Omit<City, "id"> & {
    id?: string
} 

// CityCorrect will now have the type
/* 
type CityCorrect {
    name: string
    id?: number
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, try it

```
type NullablePropertiesToOptional<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: null extends T[K] ?  T[K] | undefined : T[K]
}

type Result = NullablePropertiesToOptional<MyType>;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).