# Using undefined instead of null for optional fields in prisma-client-js

Tags: typescript, prisma

I am using Prisma with MongoDB, and I have a model with optional fields as shown below in TypeScript:

```js
model user {
    id         String     @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    username   String
    password   String
    name       String?
    surname    String?
}
```

The resulting generated TypeScript type for the 'user' model is:

```js
export declare type User = {
    id: string
    username: string
    password: string
    name: string | null
    surname: string | null
}
```

The issue arises when attempting to check for type overlap between the generated 'User' type and another type I am using. This other type is also generated, but it comes from another package, and I do not have the flexibility to modify it. As a result, an error is thrown during the type check.

I have tries to find a solution for this problem, but unfortunately, I could not find any helpful resources or suggestions.

My final question is: Is there a way to specify to `prisma-client-js` to use `undefined` for optional fields, or is there a method to modify the way it generates TypeScript types for optional fields?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, but there is a workaround, you can use `Prisma.UserCreateInput` or `Prisma.UserCreateManyInput`:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

// It's a bit of a hack though
type UserOptional = Prisma.UserCreateManyInput
```

Or you can use TypeScript to create a new type out of `User`, e.g. using this answer [How to make nullable properties optional in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165227/how-to-make-nullable-properties-optional-in-typescript):

```
type PickNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? P : never]: T[P]
}

type PickNotNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? never : P]: T[P]
}

type OptionalNullable<T> = {
  [K in keyof PickNullable<T>]?: Exclude<T[K], null>
} & {
  [K in keyof PickNotNullable<T>]: T[K]
}

type UserOptional = OptionalNullable<User>
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, however, according to [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-js/issues/572) it doesn't seem possible.
Which is logical to me, since on a database level, you generally wouldn't have "undefined" fields, you would have null fields.
To avoid overlapping type issues, you can use aliasing when importing or change your schema User type name to something else, eg: APIUser