# Make nullable properties of interface optional without strict null checks

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Let's say I have an interface like so:

```
interface iUser {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  phone: string | null;
  age: number | null;
}
```

I'm trying to use generics to create a version of this interface that sets all nullable properties to optional (but does not remove the possibility of them being null). So, something like `type CreateUser = NullableOptional<iUser>`, which would be equivalent to the following using iUser as the type argument:

```
type CreateUser = {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  phone?: string | null;
  age?: number | null 
}
```

I have seen this question: [How to make nullable properties optional in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165227/how-to-make-nullable-properties-optional-in-typescript), which suggests the following:

```
type PickNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? P : never]: T[P]
}

type PickNotNullable<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as null extends T[P] ? never : P]: T[P]
}

type OptionalNullable<T> = {
  [K in keyof PickNullable<T>]?: Exclude<T[K], null>
} & {
  [K in keyof PickNotNullable<T>]: T[K]
}
```

But it appears to require `strictNullChecks` to be enabled, which we can't do at the moment (we're working toward that goal, but we're not there yet).

Without it, `PickNullable<T>` and `PickNotNullable<T>` are not working properly for me. If I create a simple type and try to use PickNullable, the resulting type is equivalent to the original:

```
type Foo = {
  id: number;
  name: string | null;
}

type NullableFoo = PickNullable<Foo>;

// NullableFoo is equivalent to Foo
```

And PickNotNullable does not return any properties at all, no matter the type I pass in.

Is it possible to do this without having `strictNullChecks` enabled?

Comment: *"NullableFoo is equivalent to Foo"* [Not as far as I can tell](https://tsplay.dev/w1QEGw), it's `{ name: string | null; }` as I'd expect. And `PickNotNullable<Foo>` returns `{ id: number; }` ([link](https://tsplay.dev/w2Q58W)). Finally, using `OptionalNullable` instead of `PickNullable` [seems to provide what you're looking for](https://tsplay.dev/WJrAkW). So....?

Comment: Right now this seems either to be a duplicate of the other question, or not reproducible.  Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Right, I was using OptionalNullable in conjunction with these two types, and I see that it's working in the playground, but if I copy and paste the exact same code into my file in VSCode PickNullable<Foo> is the same as Foo every time, so OptionalNullable obviously won't work

Comment: @DillonBrock - Very odd. I can't replicate that locally. What version of TypeScript are you using? What does your `tsconfig.json` look like? (And how are you determining that the result is the same as `Foo`? What is it you're seeing to make you say that?)

Comment: Using TS 4.9.3, but I think I've just realized that the problem is we don't have strict null checks enabled in our app, because when I enable them the types work as expected. And I was just using the intellisense in vscode to show me the type after assigning the type to a variable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is there a way to create types like this without enabling strict null checks? We want to restructure our typing to allow for it but it's going to be a long time before that's possible

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that, I have virtually no experience with TypeScript without `"strict": true`. :-) @jcalz?

Comment: Without `—strictNullChecks`everything is “nullable”.  The type `X | null` is indistinguishable from `X`, so I don’t think we can do much of anything here.